# How to install AWS CLI tools in a docker image without pip?

Tags: docker

I'm using the [dotnet-sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/2.2/sdk/stretch/amd64/Dockerfile) image and would like to install [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) into it - but no `pip`, `unzip`, or even the `setuptools` Python module is available.

How can I get the AWS CLI tools going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it going - forgot to chmod+x. You can do the following:

```
curl -sL "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
python -m zipfile -e awscli-bundle.zip .
chmod +x ./awscli-bundle/install
./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```